# InfiniteContainer not working properly codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am using an infiniteContainer in codenameone but it doesn't seem to be working properly. When I load components onto the infinitecontainer for the first time it freezes and can't seem to scroll for more components to be displayed. The container also sometimes adds the endmarker half way when creating a component. Have been finding a workaround for months and it is really frustrating.

Comment: You will need to post a test case showing how you use the API.

Comment: Hi Shai. I have figured it out, but the app freezes after scrolling for some time and I am loading only 5 components at a time. What could be causing it to freeze

Comment: Make sure you aren't blocking the EDT. You need to use `invokeAndBlock` if you want to do asynchronous work in an infinite container